# Express validator - validate all route named params

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I'd like to validate all route named parameters using express validator. I was trying to do this in the middleware but it's not working. How can I achieve this? Bellow simplified version of my code.

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  const routeParameters = Object.keys(req.params);

  for (const parameter of routeParameters) {
    param(parameter).isInt()
  }

  next();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  const routeParameters = Object.keys(req.params);

  const invalidParams = [];

  for (const parameter of routeParameters) {
    if (!param(parameter).isInt()) {
      invalidParams.push(param);
    }
  }

  if (invalidParams.length) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({
        message: `The following parameters are invalid: [ ${invalidParams.join(", ")} ]`
      });
  }
  next();
};
```

Comment: I'm handling checking for validation errors in the separate middleware so can't return response from here. Additionally I'd like to have information about errors from all parameters.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the use case - if the parameters fail the validation here (i.e. they are not ints) you want to continue the request and validate it later?

Comment: Let's say the first parameter fails validation. I'd like to store this error and check other parameters, so I can return all errors later. It's a standard behavior of express validator.

Comment: I've updated the answer to hopefully reflect the case you are describing